# No button ID to run await page.click('#submit');

Tags: node.js, button, puppeteer

I'm trying to run await page.click('#submit');

I can't find the button id, it doesn't seem to be submit. Here's what I get from the element:

```
    <div class="ws-plugin--s2member-pro-login-widget-submit">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Log Me In">
    </div>
```

Any idea how I can get this to work?

Comment: Not sure what `page.click` is but - I don't see any `id="submit"`?! (Also, using ID submit is not wise.) Have you tried with `".ws-plugin--s2member-pro-login-widget-submit [type='submit']"` ? Or rather start from a parent with some ID to be more specific. Using a class might not lead to the desired element - but to the *first* in the DOM - which might not be *the one*.

Comment: Welcome to SO! More context is probably needed here, as Roko mentions. Surely, there are other selectors on the page, so there's no telling that providing a selector that works on these two elements in isolation will work in the larger context. Also, there can be JS behavior that interferes with the selector visibility and functionality even when you have the right one. What site are you manipulating and what is the ultimate goal?

Comment: thanks for taking a look into this, both of you! As you can tell, I'm not exactly experienced. @RokoC.Buljan, the output I get is Error: Evaluation failed: DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#.ws-plugin--s2member-pro-login-widget-submit' is not a valid selector. I'm trying to log into this page to then run an automated test of the form as it has previously failed to work and it took weeks to even notice: https://triumph-foundation.org/exchange-login/ entering username and password works, it's just pressing the login button that's giving me a hard time.

Comment: `#.` clearly this is not a right selector. Please learn DOM selectors `#` stands for ID, `.` stands for Class. There's no such `#.`